# Using Firebase Package in flutter error (flutter fire UI): "Null check operator used on null value" when using ProfileScreen()

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-auth-in-flutter-apps#5) to build user authentication UI pages using the *flutterfire_ui/auth.dart* package. Note that the only major modification I made that is different from tutorial is that I used CuptertinoApp() instead of MaterialApp(). Below is my home page where are want to direct users to a profile page after they have clicked the "person" icon.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterfire_ui/auth.dart';
import 'package:night_sounds/screens/login_screen.dart';

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 111, 146, 105),
  // Nav bar
  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    border: null,
    // leading: Container(), //need this or no?
    trailing: CupertinoButton(
      child: const Icon(
        CupertinoIcons.person,
        color: Color.fromARGB(200, 225, 225, 225),
        size: 30,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          CupertinoPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ProfileScreen(
              providerConfigs: const [EmailProviderConfiguration()],
              cupertinoNavigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                middle: const Text('User Profile'),
                trailing: CupertinoButton(
                  child: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.arrow_left_circle),
                  onPressed: () {
                    SignedOutAction((context) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),

    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: Transform.translate(
      offset: const Offset(0, -30),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'assets/images/fb_icon.png',
            width: 275,
            height: 300,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          CupertinoButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // need to build a pop-up function here
            },
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 74, 186, 102),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 25,
              vertical: 10,
            ),
            child: const Text('Quick Start'),
          ),
          const SignOutButton(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

The part in question is where I use

```
builder: (context) => ProfileScreen(...)
```

it should return the authentification page from the flutterfire package. Instead,I'm getting

> Null check operator used on a null value

This is the full output from the terminal:

> The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder(dirty): Null
> check operator used on a null value
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:   Builder
> Builder:file:///Users/lliu56/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutterf
> ire_ui-0.4.3+20/lib/src/auth/screens/profile_screen.dart:495:14
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      ProfileScreen.buildPage (package:flutterfire_ui/src/auth/screens/profile_screen.dart:504: 34)
> #1      Builder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:7531:48)
> #2      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5156:49)
> #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5086:15)
> #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
> #5      ComponentElement.*firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5068:5)
> #6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5062:5) ...     Normal
> element mounting (7 frames)
> #13     FlutterFireUIThemeElement.mount (package:flutterfire_ui/src/auth/styling/theme.dart:79:11) ...
>
> Normal element mounting (7 frames)
> #20     ScreenElement.mount (package:flutterfire_ui/src/auth/screens/internal/multi_provider*
> screen.dart:54:11) ...     Normal element mounting (30 frames)
> #50     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
> #51     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6570:36)
> #52     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6582:32) ...     Normal
> element mounting (178 frames)
> #230    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
> #231    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6570:36)
> #232    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6582:32) ...     Normal
> element mounting (460 frames)
> #692    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3971:16)
> #693    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3702:20)
> #694    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5111:16)
> #695    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:7)
> #696    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2780:19)
> #697    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:903:21)
> #698    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
> #699    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
> #700    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
> #701    SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame. (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:939:7)
> #705    _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:189:12) (elided 3 frames from
> class _Timer and dart:async-patch)

Note that I also tried it with MaterialApp() and it shows the same output.